# Migrate column data into new join table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I need to migrate a table column's data to a Join Table which will hold the relationship between the old rows and new indexes.

Is there a standard way to do this in Rails?

Comment: shouldn't you do that in plain SQL? Try adding some more detail to make it clearer what you need. (From Review)

Comment: Backup first. Then create table, try to write code to migrate the old data to join table.